# Can i bundle SPF-Records so that my clients only need to add one?

Tags: email, spf

**My question needs some explanation first:**

I provide an E-Mail-service for several clients. Depnding on the type of the E-Mail (reservation, offer,...) i send those mails from different servers. Therefore i've been including multiple ip Adresses to the clients domains as SPF records.
The Record looks somthing like this:

> v=spf1 ip4:xxx.xx.xxx.xx  ip4:xxx.xx.xxx.xx  ip4:xxx.xx.xxx.xx -all

All those ips are for my service.

Now while checking a clients SPF records i sar that Outlook includes just one Subdomain for their Outlook 365 like this:

> v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all

An when i check the SPF-Records of "spf.protection.outlook.com" it shows me these:

> v=spf1 ip4:207.46.101.128/26 ip4:207.46.100.0/24 ip4:207.46.163.0/24
>   ip4:65.55.169.0/24 ip4:157.56.110.0/23 ip4:157.55.234.0/24
>   ip4:213.199.154.0/24 ip4:213.199.180.0/24
>   include:spfa.protection.outlook.com -all

(like you can see here: https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=spf%3aspf.protection.outlook.com&run=toolpage)

**So my question now is:**

Could i also create a single subdomain, which i add to my clients SPF-Records and then manage all of them centralized by simply changing the SPF-Records of my subdomain?
If yes? Do i need to consider anything when creating that subdomain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create one SPF record for a SPF sub-domain and then includes that sub-domain in all your customers SPF record, you will only have to edit the common SPF record, if one of the servers changes address. Eg:

TXT record for spf.example.com:

`v=spf1 ip4:xxx.xx.xxx.xx ip4:xxx.xx.xxx.xx ip4:xxx.xx.xxx.xx -all`

TXT record for one of the customer domains:

`v=spf1 include:spf.example.com -all`

Then you just have to keep the spf.example.com record updated.

Comment: Thanks for the info! According to my tests it seems to work very well. I'm still waiting for my clients agency to add the record on their domain. As soon as they're done I'll tell you my results!

Comment: Thank's! It worked. I clicked "The answer was useful, but Stack Overflow won't schow it until i'm more experienced here" :)